# String conversion from one formt to other using packages

Tags: go

Say I have a string "a-b-c-d ", if the string is separated by "-", I want to replace "-" by ":" else I want the string to remain same. How do I do that in Go?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data := "01-12-13-14-15-16"
    //  mac :="11:11:11:11:11:11"

    // Split on comma.
    result := strings.Split(data, "-")
    result1 :=strings.Join(result,":")

    //  result11 := strings.Split(mac, "-")
    //result12 :=strings.Join(mac,":")

    fmt.Print(result1)
    //fmt.Print(result12)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) function in standard library:

```
result1 := strings.Replace(data, "-", ":", -1)
```

Comment: what is the -1 arg?

Comment: it tells how often the string shall be replaced,
-1 says all occurrences, 
but it's also stated in the docu @ain posted...